# ODBC SQLBindCol bind ODBC float type to return as std::string

Tags: c++, odbc

I am storing a database record with a float field stored with the SQL queries

```
create table test_table_3 (a float, b varchar(10));
insert into test_table_3 VALUES (1.4, 'foo');
```

I want to define a function that returns the values of the records as std::string.

The attached program does that, but the return value as string is "1.39999". Would there be a way to set the ODBC API to return the same value as inserted ("1.4"). (This is just because the code needs to be used in a test that matches input with output values)

I am using [SQLBindCol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlbindcol-function?view=sql-server-ver15) ODBC function to define the "TargetType" parameter (identifier of the C data type) in the program as

```
bind_data[idx].target_type = SQL_C_CHAR;
```

[ODBC C Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/c-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15)

Complete program is:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <windows.h>
#endif
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct bind_column_data_t
{
  SQLSMALLINT target_type; //the C data type of the result data
  SQLPOINTER target_value_ptr; //pointer to storage for the data
  SQLINTEGER buf_len; //maximum length of the buffer being bound for data (including null-termination byte for char)
  SQLLEN strlen_or_ind; //number of bytes(excluding the null termination byte for character data) available
  //to return in the buffer prior to calling SQLFetch
};

const std::string conn("Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=test_db;");
int exec_direct(SQLHSTMT hstmt, const std::string& sql);
int fetch(SQLHSTMT hstmt, const std::string& sql);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//main
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
  SQLHENV  henv = SQL_NULL_HENV; //environment
  SQLHDBC  hdbc = SQL_NULL_HDBC; //connection handle
  SQLHSTMT hstmt = SQL_NULL_HSTMT; //statement handle

  std::string sql1 = "drop table if exists test_table_3;";
  std::string sql2 = "create table test_table_3 (a float, b varchar(10));";
  std::string sql3 = "insert into test_table_3 VALUES (1.4, 'foo');";
  std::string sql4 = "select * from[test_table_3];";

  if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv)))
  {
  }
  if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0)))
  {
  }
  if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc)))
  {
  }
  if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLSetConnectAttr(hdbc, SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, (SQLPOINTER)TRUE, 0)))
  {
  }
  if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, NULL, (SQLCHAR*)conn.c_str(), SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE)))
  {
    return -1;
  }
  if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &hstmt)))
  {
  }

  exec_direct(hstmt, sql1);
  exec_direct(hstmt, sql2);
  exec_direct(hstmt, sql3);
  fetch(hstmt, sql4);

  SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt);
  SQLDisconnect(hdbc);
  SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc);
  SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);
  return 0;

  return 0;
}


int exec_direct(SQLHSTMT hstmt, const std::string& sql)
{
  if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)sql.c_str(), SQL_NTS)))
  {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

int fetch(SQLHSTMT hstmt, const std::string& sql)
{
  SQLSMALLINT nbr_cols;
  SQLCHAR* sqlstr = (SQLCHAR*)sql.c_str();
  struct bind_column_data_t* bind_data = NULL;

  if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLExecDirect(hstmt, sqlstr, SQL_NTS)))
  {
    return -1;
  }

  if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLNumResultCols(hstmt, &nbr_cols)))
  {
  }

  bind_data = (bind_column_data_t*)malloc(nbr_cols * sizeof(bind_column_data_t));
  for (SQLUSMALLINT idx = 0; idx < nbr_cols; idx++)
  {
    bind_data[idx].target_value_ptr = NULL;
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //get column names
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  for (SQLUSMALLINT idx = 0; idx < nbr_cols; idx++)
  {
    SQLCHAR buf[1024];
    SQLSMALLINT sqltype = 0;
    SQLSMALLINT scale = 0;
    SQLSMALLINT nullable = 0;
    SQLSMALLINT len = 0;
    SQLULEN sqlsize = 0;

    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLDescribeCol(
      hstmt,
      idx + 1,
      (SQLCHAR*)buf, //column name
      sizeof(buf) / sizeof(SQLCHAR),
      &len,
      &sqltype,
      &sqlsize,
      &scale,
      &nullable)))
    {
    }
  }

  for (SQLUSMALLINT idx = 0; idx < nbr_cols; idx++)
  {
    bind_data[idx].target_type = SQL_C_CHAR;
    bind_data[idx].buf_len = (1024 + 1);
    bind_data[idx].target_value_ptr = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * bind_data[idx].buf_len);
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //SQLBindCol assigns the storage and data type for a column in a result set,
  //including:
  //a storage buffer that will receive the contents of a column of data
  //the length of the storage buffer
  //a storage location that will receive the actual length of the column of data
  //returned by the fetch operation data type conversion
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  for (SQLUSMALLINT idx = 0; idx < nbr_cols; idx++)
  {
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLBindCol(
      hstmt,
      idx + 1,
      bind_data[idx].target_type,
      bind_data[idx].target_value_ptr,
      bind_data[idx].buf_len,
      &(bind_data[idx].strlen_or_ind))))
    {
    }
  }

  size_t nbr_rows = 0;
  while (SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLFetch(hstmt)))
  {
    for (int idx_col = 0; idx_col < nbr_cols; idx_col++)
    {
      std::string str;
      if (bind_data[idx_col].strlen_or_ind != SQL_NULL_DATA)
      {
        str = (char*)bind_data[idx_col].target_value_ptr;
      }
      else
      {
        str = "NULL";
      }
      std::cout << str << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    nbr_rows++;
  }

  for (SQLUSMALLINT idx_col = 0; idx_col < nbr_cols; idx_col++)
  {
    if (bind_data[idx_col].target_value_ptr != NULL)
    {
      free(bind_data[idx_col].target_value_ptr);
    }
  }
  if (bind_data != NULL)
  {
    free(bind_data);
  }
  SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt);
  return 0;
}
```

Output is :

> 1.3999999999999999 foo

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQL.  A `float` datatype has limited precision and not every value is representable.  This is why you never use `float` or `double` for storing monetary values:   Here is a related question:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency   Your column shouldn't be declared `float` or `double`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Yes. A bit of context on the question. this is to an existing database, not my choice on the data type. The goal is to compare some values that were inserted on the table previously with a current insertion of the same value. So, the value is "1.4" and must come out as string "1.4". It would be possible to obtain the value as a C float type, but that defeats the purpose, by the reasons you mentioned. Edited the title to mention that is just an ODBC issue. The question is if by means of the ODBC API, if it's possible to achieve this.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah. The database is MS SQL server. It would interesting to find out  the internal representation that MSSQL does for this insertion of float "1.4".  Is the value converted from the string "1.4" in the SQL query to a C float type? In that case, it may or may not be possible to get an accurate same value. But if not, if MSSQL just stores some internal representation of "1.4" "as-is" , then it might be, it they made a public API for that.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is for MS SQL Server, it's possible to use the [STR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function with a length of 3 characters and precision of 1, to match exactly the string "1.4"

```
INSERT INTO test_table_3 VALUES (1.4, 'foo');
SELECT STR(a,3,1), b FROM[test_table_3];
```

Output

```
1.4 foo
```